# How to make middle ware in Nodejs with express

Tags: node.js, express

I'm making express router.
There is some codes like below.
But when I run node this file, it doesn't work.
I think this part make some problem. 
This works in Koa but not express.
Could you give me some advice?

```
const printInfo = (req) => {
  req.body = {
    method: req.method,
    path: req.path,
    params: req.params,
  };
};
```

This is the codes in a row.

```
const express = require('express');
const posts = express.Router();

const printInfo = (req) => {
  req.body = {
    method: req.method,
    path: req.path,
    params: req.params,
  };
};

posts.get('/', printInfo);

module.exports = posts;
```

and

```
const express = require('express');

const api = express.Router();
const posts = require('./posts');

api.use('/posts', posts);

module.exports = api;
```

and

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
const api = require('./api/index');

app.use('/api', api);

app.listen(4000, () => {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 4000!');
});
```

Comment: Could you please a little bit more specific about your problem, maybe post the error you get when running the script.

**Note:**
[Express middle-wares](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) take two arguments (req, res), you need the `res` object in order to send back responses.
It seems like you are not sending a response back, you should send a response back in order to get anything back from the server

Comment: thx!! You're right.

Answer (score 0):

Your middleware miss the next() call and the router is not configured properly.

Follow this example, is how I always used middleware with Expressjs

middleware.js

```
// no need to import express/router

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {

  // manipulate your body obj
  req.body = {
    method: req.method,
    path: req.path,
    params: req.params,
  };

  // go to the next function
  next();

}
```

routes.js

```
// only import the router
const router = require('express').Router();

// function for /api/posts
router.route('/posts').post( (req, res) => {
    // req.body has been manipulated from the middleware
    // do anything you like and call res
    res.send("...")
});

// other routes

module.exports = router;
```

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const middleware = require('./middleware');
const routes = require('./routes');

const app = express();

// all calls to /api/* execute the middleware first
app.use('/api', middleware);

// execute the other routes functions
app.use('/api', routes);

app.listen(4000, () => {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 4000!');
});
```